# python-get a sublist without changing position

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic

Hi I am working on Genetic Algorithm. I wondering if someone can help me with the
cross-over step.

Example:

```
dad=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mom=[2,3,6,1,7,5,4]
```

I want to pick a random subset in dad, the size of the subset can also be random. For example, [1,2,3] or [3,4,5] or[2,3,4] or [1,2] or [4,5] or [1,2,3,4] but they must be in the original order in dad.

So for example, random subset is [2,3,4,5]
Then I want my offspring to be [,2,3,4,5,,]. Then I would like to fill up the empty spot using mom's list. I want to iterate mom's list. First consider 2, 2 is already in the list, so I skip 2. Then consider 3, 3 is also already in the list offspring, so i skip 3. Then 6, 6 is not in the offspring list so i will add 6 to the first available spot. so offspring is now [6,2,3,4,5,,]. Eventually, `offspring` should be `[6,2,3,4,5,1,7]`

Any help will be much much appreciated!
I think the hardest part I need help with is how to get to this step `[,2,3,4,5,,]`
The iteration through mom's list probably doable for me.

updated code

```
dad=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mom=[2,3,6,1,7,5,4]

upper=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
lower=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
slice=dad[lower:upper]
child=copy.deepcopy(dad)

j =0
for i in child:
    if i not in slice:
        child[j] = 0
    j+=1   
n=len(child)
h=0
k=0
while k <= len(child)-1:
    if child[k] == 0:
        if mom[h] not in slice:
            child[k]=mom[h]
            h+=1
            k+=1
        else:
            h+=1
    else:
        k+=1
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?  Although you have an algorithm outlined, step by step, you're unable to write a *single line of code* to solve the task?  Look up the **random** package for generating pseduo-random numbers; that can get you that initial step.

Comment: Don't ask *us* how this looks: ask Python.  What does this program do?  (Hint: you left out one of my suggestions, checking the values of lower & upper, so it's not yet fully functional.)

Comment: Also, we're not likely to read through and desk-check code with one-letter variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Generate two random integers in the range len(dad) (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for usage).  These are the limits of your random subset; call them **lower** and **upper**.

Make a copy of **dad**.  For the subranges 0:lower and upper+1:-1 (last element), replace that element of **dad_copy** with available elements of **mom**, in order.  You can use a simple counter to keep track of where you are in **mom**, advancing if that element is already in the list:

```
while mom[i] in dad_copy:
    i += 1
```

Is that enough to move you to the coding stage?

---

OP CODE ATTEMPT:

It's great to see you get this far.  You don't need **deepcopy** for this, just a normal full-slice copy (see my change to that line).

```
import random 
dad = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mom = [2,3,6,1,7,5,4]
upper = random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
lower = random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
# Note: if lower > upper, you have to switch them.
#    If they're equal, you need to change one.

slice = dad[lower:upper]
child = dad[:]   # Easier way to get a shallow copy

for i in child: 
    if i not in slice:
         i == 0
```

I'm afraid you lost focus here.  You need to step through all of the positions *outside* the lower:upper range.  Also, I have no idea what your'e trying to do with **i == 0**; a bare comparison does no good, and an assignment to **i** would spoil your loop.
Keep working through this; these are skills you need to develop.  It looks like you may have skipped some exercises before you started this assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I guess I can slice dad using dad[lower:upper] but I'm not sure how to keep their position

Comment: Don't bother; that slice concatenation was too simple.  Copy **dad**, and then just change the elements outside that range.  The copy puts them naturally into the right place.

Comment: i am so sorry. i am very new to python. I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: import copy
import random

dad=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mom=[2,3,6,1,7,5,4]

upper=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
lower=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
slice=dad[lower:upper]
child=copy.deepcopy(dad)

for i in child:
    if i not in slice:
        i == 0

#for i in slice:
 #   for j in range(len(mom)):
  #      if mom[j] not in slice:
   #         child[]

Comment: sorry I tried to copy a code i wrote but it doesnt show in the code format

Comment: Code updates go into your question.  Comments don't format code.

Comment: Post comments on the entire question under the question, not under my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
dad=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mom=[2,3,6,1,7,5,4]
upper=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
lower=random.randint(0,len(dad)-1)
slice=dad[lower:upper]
#Find elements from mom only
from_mom = [e for e in mom if e not in slice]
#Append elements from mom to the start and end of the child list.
child = from_mom[0:lower]+slice+from_mom[lower:]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.